# Remove certain characters from multiple files with whitepsaces

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed

I'm trying to rename a bunch of music tracks in a directory, but I got this error:

> When moving multiple files, last argument must be a directory

This is the script:

```
for file in * ; do
    mv $file  $(echo $file |sed 's/^.\{5\}//g')
done
```

This works for a file without whitespace, how would I modify this script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
mv -- "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed ...)"
```

Else `mv` sees multiple arguments. A filename called `file name with spaces` would be 4 arguments for `mv`. Therefore the error: `when moving multiple files, last argument must be a directory`. When `mv` has more than 2 arguments, it's assuming you want to move multiple files to a directory (which would then be the last argument).

---

But however, it looks like you want to remove the first 5 characters from the filename. That can be done simpler with `bash`:

```
mv -- "$file" "${file:5}"
```

---

**Edit**: I added the `--` flag, thanks to the comment of @[pabouk](https://serverfault.com/users/84914/pabouk). Now file starting with dash `-` are also correctly processed.

Comment: That may not work with file names beginning by `-`. Instead of `echo "$file"` use `printf '%s\n' "$file"`.

Comment: I forgot about `mv`. :) You handled that case :) --- What I meant was problem with `echo` itself. For example GNU echo (both standalone and bash built-in) will not print these strings: `-n`, `-e` and `-E`. Even according to the POSIX definition it is not possible to use `echo` reliably because certain situations are undefined. XSI compliant `echo` will interpret backslash escape sequences. --- `printf '%s\n'` does not have such unwanted and implementation dependant effects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use prename, which is often distributed together with Perl. (For example, in Debian, /usr/bin/prename is installed by the `perl` package.) If not packaged by your distribution (look for `prename` and `rename` in the conventional binaries locations), it is available for download from a number of places, such as for example [here](https://gist.github.com/javiermon/3939556), [here](https://github.com/statico/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/rename) or [here](http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt).

This script takes a regular expression to apply to each of the file names, and a set of file names, and modifies the names of those files according to that regular expression.

For example, you might do

```
prename -v -n 's/^.{5}//' *
```

to show what would happen if you remove the first five characters in the file names. To actually execute the rename, you simply remove the `-n`.